# Drag and drop images and post data to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am using http://jsfiddle.net/28SMv/8/ to drag and drop images. Then I need to retrieve the image information from dropped area. 
I would like to insert a form for dropped area and would like to post the data.

How can I do that using PHP? Anyone have other example for retrieving image information(imageid) from dropped area?

Comment: What **specifically** do you want to know?

Comment: You can look at the dropped element in the drop event, which could possibly include the image name or id or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Script :**

```
$( "span").draggable({ revert: "invalid" });

        $( "#box1" ).droppable({
            accept: "#wrap1 span",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                id=ui.draggable.attr('id');
                $('#frm').append('<input type="text" value="'+id+'" id="i'+id+'"><br><br>');
                //or do what you want exactly like above code
            }
        });

        $( "#wrap1" ).droppable({
            accept: "#wrap1 span",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                id=ui.draggable.attr('id');
                $('#frm #i'+id).remove();
            }
        });
```

**Html :**

```
<style>
.custom-state-active { background: #eee; }

.left{
    float:left;
}
.right{
    float:left;
}

#wrap1{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
    margin:10px;
    clear:both;
}
#box1{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid green;
    height:100px;
    margin:10px;
    clear:both;
}
span{
    float:left;
    margin:3px;
    border:1px solid #0CF;
}

</style>
<div class="left">
    <div id="wrap1">
        <span id="img1">test1--->1</span>
        <span id="img2">test1--->2</span>
    </div>


</div>

<div class="right">
    <div id="box1"></div>
</div>

<form id="frm" style="float:left; margin:10px;" action="test.php" method="post">
</form>
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/3qJdp/

You can create/remove form elements(use hidden input box) after drop succeed.
Finally you can post the form date.

I hope this helps you little bit

Answer (score 0):

What you are going to want to do is create a form and use javascript to create hidden form elements which will store which images have been dragged to which location. When the user submits the form the data will be passed to your script where you can do what ever you want.

This hidden element creation could be hooked up to a drag and drop event to add or remove an element as necessary.

Comment: Anyone can please show me how to do this? Though I am new to jquery and javascript, I am learning this kind of stuffs..:(:(

Comment: @NewPHP: why don't you **learn** from the very basics of js then? Take ready to use code and paste it into your project **is not** a learning process.